# How is the week referred when there is no parsha read that Shabbat?

Tags: calendar

Frequently, I have seen on wedding invitations and other correspondences that refer to a date using the parsha name for that week. E.g. an invitation to a wedding may say יום שני בשבת פרשת בא - The second day of the week of parshat Bo.

How do they refer to a week when no parsha is read because of Yom Tov of Hol Hamo'ed? Do they refer to it using the name of the Yom Tov such as יום שני בשבת שבועות - The 2nd day of the week of Shabbat Shavu'ot? Or do they use the name of the parsha to be read the following week? I can see that using that 2nd option would be confusing.

I am seeking an answer that addresses the situation when an event is not on Yom Tov or Hol Hamo'ed itself, but, rather before a Yom Tov occurring later in the week and part of that Yom Tov extends in to Shabbat thus deferring the weekly parsha.

Comment: You call it “this Shabbos” or “The 31st day of Month Ploni”

Comment: @DonielF "this Shabbos" doesn't work for future-planned events, usually.

Answer (score 4):

My Bar Mitzvah was the week of Pesach. On the invitation, I was told to put:

> ביום שבת קודש, ביום א' דפסח

And for the following Monday:

> ביום שני, יום א' דחול המועד פסח

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In view of it, I see that I need to edit my question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: @DanF I don't think there are strict rules to how you write it and often times people don't mention the parsha at all. In this case, it may make sense to just give the date without mentioning Shabbos or say something like יום שני לפני חג השבועות (Monday before Shavuot), but either way give the date.

Comment: Probably true, and, perhaps, this is done. I'm just curious as to what's common protocol.